# Passing a 2d array to a function if I don't know the dimensions

Tags: c

I am trying to write a C function to add two arrays. The function should work with any array sizes and it should receive a reference to both arrays and the number of rows and the number of columns and it should return a pointer to the first element of the resulting array.
How would I do that? When I try to pass a two dimensional array to a function I get an error?

```
#include<stdio.h>
void function(int r, int c,int a[][]){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            printf("%d, ",a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

 }

int main(){
    int array[2][2] = {{1,2},{4,5}};
    function(2,2,array);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you writing a C++ function, or a C function? Tags say C, but the question says C++.

Comment: Is that a homework? That sounds awful like a homework

Comment: This is  `C` it is not `C++`

Comment: This is C not C++ sorry

Comment: "write a C function to add two arrays" --> There is no adding here.  Should  one want to "add" 2 arrays, code may be _easy_ to code with `void function(int r, int c,int *a,,int *b,,int *sum){`.  Even with C89.

Comment: I am just testing how i can pass an array as an argument to the function

Answer (score 4):

Assuming C99, or C11 with an implementation that doesn't define `__STDC_NO_VLA__`, you could use the variable length array (VLA) notation and could write:

```
void function(int r, int c, int a[r][c])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
            printf("%d, ", a[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Or something equivalent to that.  The dimensions must be defined before they're used in the array specification.

If you don't have access to even a C99 compiler but only a C90 compiler, then you have to pass a pointer to the first element of the array and the sizes and you perform the array index calculation explicitly.

```
void function(int r, int c, int *a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
            printf("%d, ", a[i * c + j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Now you call the function like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    int array[2][2] = { { 1, 2 }, { 4, 5 } };
    function(2, 2, &array[0][0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't there any other way if i am using an older version of C

Comment: You can pass the address of element 0 and do the subscript calculation yourself.  I’m not at a computer right now so I’ll add an alternative later. But you should get a compiler that supports the standards of the current millennium.

Comment: @YousifDafalla You can look at the 4th option [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pass-2d-array-parameter-c/).

Comment: @YousifDafalla: I've added the alternative that you'll need to use if you can't use a VLA.